# Will the ESR rule still work if the $sort comes after a data transforming stage but is still sorting on an untransformed field?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-indexes

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      country: "USA",
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      B: "cheese"
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "A": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 10
  }
])
```

In this pipeline, there is a $set stage which transforms the documents by adding a new field. However, the $sort is still performed on an original untransformed field, so will the ESR rule still apply assuming that there is a compound index on `country, A`?

Comment: That is what [explain](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/) is for.  Try using explain on the query and see if it has a sort stage.

Comment: @Joe here is a [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fBzoWHLKJh6) replicating `explain`. Actually from my understanding, ESR rule is an indexing strategy but not some strict rules. Therefore, I do not quite understand what `ESR rule work` means.

Comment: I asking whether the index will be used to optimize the sort and limit portion of the query.

Comment: @ray how do you set up indexes in the playground?

Comment: @BearBileFarmsisTorture just use the mgodatagen syntax. I think only mgodatagen support index in playground as of now.

Comment: @ray if a field is an array of embedded documents, how would I specify that using mgodatagen? what is the type?

Comment: @BearBileFarmsisTorture I am not sure about that. May need some time to try with the [syntax](https://github.com/feliixx/mgodatagen)

Comment: @ray actually, the `explain` doesn't reveal whether or not the index was use to aid the sorting stage. It reveals that the index was used during the fetch stage, which is already known to be the case.

Comment: @BearBileFarmsisTorture yes, I don't know how to interpret the explain result for this case also. Just providing the replication in playground to facilitate the discussion

Comment: The important note is that in the winning plan there is a `$sort`, which indicates a blocking, in-memory sort, i.e. _not_ optimized by the index.  If you remove the `$set` stage, you can see an example where the query can use the index for sorting, and not require an in-memory sort: https://mongoplayground.net/p/fQ5QohBHrcp

Comment: @ray thank you very much for that playground, I honestly didn't if it would until you showed us that.